# Access external controller function inside directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a directive element that will take an array of json objects and create a series of buttons. To start with, I thought I would try to get working with just a left and a right button. Here's how I'm trying to use it

```
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl as form">
   <buttongroup 
      left-func="form.cancel()" left-text="Reject Call" 
      right-func="form.submit()" right-text="Accept Call">
   </buttongroup>
</div>
```

And heres the directive code

```
.directive('buttongroup', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',

      scope: {
         leftFunc: '@',
         leftText: '@',
         rightFunc: '@',
         rightText: '@'
      },

      template: '<button type="button" ng-click="{{leftFunc}}">{{leftText}}</button><button type="button" ng-click="{{rightFunc}}">{{rightText}}</button>',
   };
});
```

This creates the correct html but the `ng-click` does not work on the buttons. I'm assuming this is because they are in the directive's template scope and are unable to access the FormCtrl functions as `form.submit` or `form.cancel`.

I'm brand new to angular and still trying to figure out how the scoping works so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to invoke the function thus you need to call it.
You have a syntax error in your template. It must be like this:
Notice how I used the `ng-click` directive

```
template: '<button type="button" ng-click="leftFunc()">{{leftText}}</button><button type="button" ng-click="rightFunc()">{{rightText}}</button>'
```

Comment: This is most of the answer. The other issue is that leftFunc and rightFunc needed to be '&' not '@'. But I figured that out quickly once I saw this answer. Thanks!